# Passing php session variables to multiple pages

Tags: php, session, session-storage

I am having problems passing session variables on my website. I can echo my session variables on the advertiser/page2.php but when i go to a 3rd page the sessions are gone.

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

**login.php**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['account_id']= $account_id;
$_SESSION['user_email']= $user_email;
```

**advertiser/page2.php**

```
session_start();
```

**advertiser/page3.php**

```
session_start();
```

here are the settings on my phpinfo()

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value

session.auto_start  Off Off

session.bug_compat_42   Off Off

session.bug_compat_warn On  On

session.cache_expire    180 180

session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache

session.cookie_domain   no value    no value

session.cookie_httponly Off Off

session.cookie_lifetime 0   0

session.cookie_path /   /

session.cookie_secure   Off Off

session.entropy_file    no value    no value

session.entropy_length  0   0

session.gc_divisor  100 100

session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440

session.gc_probability  1   1

session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5

session.hash_function   0   0

session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID

session.referer_check   no value    no value

session.save_handler    files   files

session.save_path   no value    no value

session.serialize_handler   php php

session.use_cookies On  On

session.use_only_cookies    Off Off

session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: check the value of `session_id()` in all of your pages AFTER you've done `session_start()`. If you get different IDs, then your session cookie settings are incorrect, or the cookie is being lost somehow. Offhand, your session.save_path is blank, which is probably not good. No idea how PHP will react if it's not explicitly specified.

Comment: Thanks, I actually checked my ID while troubleshooting and is weird because I am getting the same ID which is good in this case. I still can figure out why the sessions are not passing.

Comment: Then check the save path. Perhaps php's unable to actually save the session files.

Comment: I added in the following path in my php5.ini file session.save_path = "webroot/tmp"  but I am getting the following error.                                                                                                                    Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(webroot/tmp/sess_qttb31r4d4q7b1eder40ati5h1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/22/9958722/html/advertisers/campaigns.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue several times with PHP and it is frustrating,

What I do not is set the Session ID using `session_id([new_session_id])` to the MD5 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)  hash of a string such as the username combined with some arbitrary string. The username is always tied to the user data.

The session ID is always recalculated (which might be a minimal performance cost) but you can always find the session when you need it, since the result is deterministic.

I am not sure if this is the BEST method, but something around that idea seems to have never failed me when dealing with maintaining sessions in PHP.